# Child entity found on SQL delete, but matching row in join table has already been deleted

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-delete

I have two entities related by a @One-To-Many relation :

Entity 1 :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DemandeTravaux")
public class **DemandeTravaux** extends ObjetPersistant {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String numeroDemande;
    private String lieuxTravaux;
    private String natureComlementaire;

    @Relation(type = TypeRelation.COMPOSITION)
    @OrderColumn(name = "ORDER_FIELD")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // @OrderBy("dateCreation ASC") --> permettrait de trier les etats sur la dateCreation
    private List<EtatDemandeTravaux> etatsDemandeTravaux = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Entity 2 :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EtatDemandeTravaux")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class **EtatDemandeTravaux** extends ObjetPersistant {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Hibernate created the join table **demand_trav_etat_demand_trav**.

I am deleting a lot of rows in multiple table, so the solution we found was to delete rows table by table, using the following query :
`DELETE FROM table WHERE ID IN (listOfIdsToDelete)`.
This solution works well and we don't really want to change it.

In the actual treatment, we have 3 steps in one Java method :
`1. DELETE FROM **demand_trav_etat_demand_trav** WHERE demande_travaux_id IN (listOfDemandeTravauxToDelete)` 
`2. DELETE FROM **EtatDemandeTravaux** WHERE id IN (listOfEtatDemandeTravauxToDelete)` 
`3. DELETE FROM **DemandeTravaux** WHERE id IN (listOfDemandeTravauxToDelete)`

I thought as I deleted the row from the join table before, I could then delete EtatDemandeTravaux entities as they are (supposedly) no longer realated to any DemandeTravaux, but I have the following error :
`"ORA-02292: integrity constraint (..) violated - child record found"` on **demand_trav_etat_demand_trav** table.

I understand the error, I just don't get why it occurs because it shouldn't be in the join table anymore.

I know that i could disable the constraint and reanable it afterward, but i'd rather not.
Is there any way to commit between the delete statements ? Thx !